# Laravel Livewire search button instead of live search

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

Is it possible to not live search but with a search button in Laravel Livewire? 
My approach is to use Alpine together with Livewire. 
But I don't get the search term injected into the $emit event :/

```
<div x-data="{ search: '' }">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." x-model="search" />
  <span x-text="search"></span>
  <button wire:click="$emit('test', search )">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K. ... its easy ^^

Just change `$emit('test', search)` to `window.livewire.emit('test', search)`

```
<div x-data="{ search: '' }">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search ..." x-model="search" />
  <span x-text="search"></span>
  <button x-on:click="window.livewire.emit('test', search)">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using livewire component inside a loop. the above window.livewire.emit will call all the loop livewire component class with same function name.

so the best practice will be to use

```
x-on:click="@this.call('functionNameInLivewireComponent', search)"
```